# Does anyone have a Pokémon/D&D crossover guide?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, game-recommendation

A friend is looking to introduce Pokémon into a standard D&D 3.5 edition game. Are there any existing resources which can help him deal with the workload?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LOL, not my cup of tea and I am not sure why anyone would do this, but here it is.

[Pokemon to D&D 3.5](https://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_d20_(3.5e_Sourcebook)/Pok%C3%A9dex)

Have fun.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend "Pokémon D&D" [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20031208053103/http://www.scshop.com:80/%7Eritaxis/). The stuff on the D&D Wiki is actually based off of it. There's less material but a nicer presentation. It's also very crossover-oriented.

Comment: The linked page has seemingly been broken/redirecting to another site since at least 2018. Even before then, the formatting of the linked page was messed up/unreadable from 2007 to 2018 (I think you posted this answer during this time). And, from December 2003 (when the site apparently lost all its data and had to restore from backups) to 2007, it looks like that page was missing links to all of its subpages. What an unfortunate history it's had... I've changed the link to point to the most recent archived version of the site (from December 8, 2003) that still has the links to those subpages.

Comment: @V2Blast That an amazing amount of effort to put into a ten-year old answer, especially considering that the user hasn't been seen for ten years either. Respect.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: Haha, to be fair, most of my "effort" was just clicking to view the previous archived version of the page over and over until I found a usable version of the page... :P